# Streaming live camera feed from Jetson Nano production board to different devices(desktop or Mobile)

Tags: interface, live-streaming, raspberry-pi2, nvidia-jetson-nano

I am using a Jetson Nano production board to capture a live feed from a camera.

If someone wants to see this live feed from the Jetson Nano production board to different devices .

How can I show this live feed to different devices such as desktop computers or mobile devices.

So, What is the recommended method or protocol to stream the live feed from the Jetson Nano to different devices?

Are there any specific libraries, frameworks, or tools that are commonly used for live streaming from a Jetson Nano?